# Detecting the selector that fires an event and returning it as a string, from a multi-selector jQuery object

Tags: jquery, string, events, jquery-selectors

If I pass a number of selectors to jQuery, how can I differentiate the selector that fires the event, and return that selector as a string? For example:

```
$('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).selector ); // logs an empty string
});
```

Comment: I used '#selector-x' as a convention to simplify the question, in reality some of the selectors that I am dealing with are more complex, such as: '#selector-x .class-y a'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to obtain the element's id attribute, grab it with `attr()`.

```
console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).attr('id') ); // returns #selector-a or another
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be useful

```
  $('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c').click(function(){
     console.log( $(this).attr('id') ); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to have the selector stored in a variable (usually a good idea anyhow), and then reference the variable inside of the click handler.

```
var collection = $('#hellacomplex .freal')
collection.click(function() {
    console.log(collection.selector);
});
```